# ASP.NET app recycle approximately every 20 minutes

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm noticing today about every 20 minutes recycle of my IIS pool on a production environment.
For obvious reasons I don't want that to happen.
I would like to understand :

1. Do I have the possibility from code to understand what triggers the recycling?
2. Do you have any idea what may be causing it?

PS.
Pool configuration:

- inactivity timeout: 9999
- CPU usage: unlimited
- Recycle at regular intervals: unlimited
  Virtual / Private Memory Recycle: Unlimited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some reasons that can cause recycling:

- an ISAPI deciding it's unhealthy
- any module crashing
- idle timeout
- cpu limiting
- adjusting app pool properties